# Как запретить сохранение картинок сайта на айфоне

Tags: javascript, iphone

Как запретить сохранение картинок сайта на айфоне.
в браузере сафари

Comment: [Disable “save image” in iOS web application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9190454/2881286)

Answer (score 1):

Перевод ответа на [похожий вопрос на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612632/disable-save-image-in-ios-web-application)

---

Я думаю, в этом случае должны помочь [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).
Просто добавь:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" style="pointer-events:none" alt="">
```

И все должно быть хорошо.

Comment: нет, это не работает на айфоне...

Comment: @ВикторВиктор, что именно не работает? как проверяешь? какой iphone? какой ios? в каком браузере смотришь? Добавь всю эту информацию в свой вопрос.

Comment: в браузере сафари только, в остальных не сохраняются

Comment: @ВикторВиктор, какие ответы на остальные вопросы? **Добавь эту информацию в свой вопрос**

Answer (score 0):

Можно вместо `img` использовать `background-image`, только, возможно, тогда картинки будут грузиться попозже. Ещё, как вариант, можно закрывать их поверх прозрачными блоками.

Answer (score 0):

```
img{-webkit-touch-callout: none;}
```